# How to compile modules inside directories (aka with dots in its name)

Tags: module, coq

I would like to import a module as

`Require Import Foo.Bar.`

Given that I have a file `Bar.v` inside directory `Foo`.

I am currently compiling this module with:

`$ coqc Foo/Bar.v`

When I try to `Require Import Foo.Bar.` I get this error:

`Error: The file Foo/Bar.vo contains library Bar
and not library Foo.Bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the `-R` option. Compile your file using `coqc -R Foo Foo Foo/Bar.v`. The `-R` flag takes two options: (1) the directory you want to add to your include path, and (2) the name you want to give in in the module namespace.

Later on, if you have some other file `Baz.v` that uses `Foo.Bar`, compile it using `coqc -R Foo Foo Baz.v`.

If you have one big project with many subdirectories, you can use `coq_makefile`, you can also use the `-R` in the toplevel to make the names consistent for all subdirectories once and for all. Have a look for instance at the [Makefile](https://github.com/micro-policies/micro-policies-coq/blob/master/Makefile) for our project, with its corresponding `coq_makefile` [source](https://github.com/micro-policies/micro-policies-coq/blob/master/Makefile.source).